# How to populate list to combobox

Tags: c#, list

I have been working on this RPG windows form game for a while, and I have been stuck on these lists for quite a while. Right now I have a HeadItems.cs where I keep the entity of all my head items, and I am creating a list to populate to a combobox where the user can switch their gear. I created a list in my HeadItems, made a static readonly from my home screen of the list, and added an item with several parameters. When I added an item using the "cboHeadItems.Items.Add(Headitem[0];" I thought that would take the first parameter, which is the string name, and populate that to the combobox.

```
public HomeScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetLabels();
            Headitem.Add(new HeadItems("Kyle's Head", 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1));

            foreach (HeadItems headitem in Headitem)
            {
                cboHeads.Items.Add(Headitem[0]);
            }
        }
```

And this is my HeadItems entity:

```
namespace Engine
{
public class HeadItems
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Ilvl { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public int Agility { get; set; }
    public int Intelligence { get; set; }
    public int Stamina { get; set; }
    List<HeadItems> Headitem { get; set; }

    public HeadItems(string name, int id, int ilvl, int strength, int agility, int intelligence,
        int stamina)
    {
        Name = name;
        ID = id;
        Ilvl = ilvl;
        Strength = strength;
        Agility = agility;
        Intelligence = intelligence;
        Stamina = stamina;

        Headitem = new List<HeadItems>();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: check out the DisplayMember property.

Comment: What's the framework? WPF, WinForms, XNA?

Comment: can you use ObserableCollection<T>?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the variable in the foreach loop

Try:

```
foreach (HeadItems headitem in Headitem)
{
    cboHeads.Items.Add(headitem.Name);
}
```

There are other problems also, your are instantiating a new collection in the constructor of your HeatItem Class. There are many way you could to it but for simplicity sake I would remove:

```
List<HeadItems> Headitem { get; set; }
```

From your class and do this:

```
public HomeScreen()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        SetLabels();
        List<HeadItems> headItems = new List<HeadItems>();
        headItems.Add(new HeadItems("Kyle's Head", 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1));

        foreach (HeadItems headItem in headItems)
        {
            cboHeads.Items.Add(headItem.Name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try bind list to control ad datasource. Look on example...

```
  public class myItem
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<myItem> s = new List<myItem>();
            s.Add(new myItem()
            {
                ItemName = "ItemA",
                Value = (object)"BB"
            });


            comboBox1.DataSource = s;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
        }
    }
```